# Python String Elements in List Are NoneType

Tags: json, python-3.x, mqtt

I'm using a MQTT server to receive a JSON payload as bytes,

```
Client sent packet to server: {"cmd":"publish","topic":"/host-in","payload":"[\"C\",\"E\",\"G\",\"B\",\"D\",\"F#\",\"A\"]"}
```

which gets converted a string and parsed. What is absolutely baffling to me is the fact that that this final statement always resolves to a `Caught exception in on_message: must be str, not NoneType`

```
import json


payload = json.loads(str(msg.payload.decode('utf-8')))
topic = msg.topic

for note in payload:
    print(note is None)
    print(note)

print("{}: {}".format(topic, payload))

chords.determine(payload)
```

Each of those `note is None` statements resolves to false, but output a string.

```
False
C
False
G#
etc.
```

I've put each of those notes into a `str(...)`, and I still got none type. What is happening?

Using that library, `chords.determine(['C', 'E', 'G'])` resolves fine.

Comment: @usr2564301 No that's my mistake, it has a [ in the payload. Editing OP